# Crawl webpages with different country languages

Tags: java, selenium, web-crawler

I have searched on web regarding my issue, but couldn't find anything proper. Since, I got stuck, I am posting my issue here in order to find at least the way I could solve it.
Please, it would be great, if I could get exact solution, but I need at least recommendations on how I can crawl webpages, where the content is in different languages, because crawler makes certain conclusions on the content of webpage.
It is principal for me to get the text in English or in German, because I made certain set of keywords in English and in German with which my crawler checks the content of webpage and verifies to certain category.
I thought of one solution, which is translating each webpage ,where the content is not in English or German with google translator, but firstly, I didn't find the exact code, which does the translation and secondly, I think it will take much time, if I translate each page, since I have thousands of pages to crawl.
I tried to find anything on web, but no sufficient solution was found.
At least, I need the recommendations from the people, who faced this sort of problems, how to make crawler comprehend the content of webpage.

Comment: *"I need exact solution"* Good luck with that.

Comment: "I need exact solution" ....

Comment: How about you try yourself first and show your work when you get stuck, then we will help. We aren't here to write people's code for them. Period.

Comment: Here...let me help you get started.  http://soo.gd/4hGW

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, I have edited my post.